# Possible to create popout window in ASP.NET MVC without JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On Microsoft's Career page (http://careers.microsoft.com/), if you click on either of the links (student... or working...) you are presented with a "popout" window. I'm curious to know if it is possible to do this without JavaScript mainly because my JavaScript knowledge is limited.

Comment: This might not be the answer you're looking for, but if you're going to be doing web development, you're going to want to learn JavaScript. Having said that, you shouldn't have to worry about writing much (if any) JavaScript to create a modal. Check out something like Twitter Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible to use the target="_new" attribute on a link tag:

```
<html>
<body>
<p> This is the page.</p>
<a target="_new" href="http://www.google.com">This is the popout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this just opens a new tab in the browser, and does not create "popup" effect mentioned in original question

Comment: True. To my knowledge this is the best you can get with straight HTML.